# I can't find the matching TypeScript type for `displayName` as a prop of `type`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-conversion

As the title states, I can't find the correct type.
I have checked DevTools and every component that I am, programmatically, looking at HAS `Component.type.displayName`.
The `type` for anything that is not a `ElementType` is a function.

The node's type is the return type for React.isValidElement extracted like this `Parameters<typeof React.isValidElement>`, because I can't be sure what it is.

**Problematic part:**

```
const node = SomeThingUnknown as Parameters<typeof React.isValidElement>;
const type = ((node as unknown) as React.ReactElement<React.FunctionComponent>).type;
const displayName = typeof type === "function" ? type.displayName || type.name || "Unknown" : type;
```

The last line is taken from the **React** repo. So I know it works.

**`node`, in VS Code, is:**

```
const type: string | ((props: any) => React.ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) =>
  React.Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => React.Component<any, any, any>)
```

**The error when I hover on `displayName` is:**

```
Property 'displayName' does not exist on type 'JSXElementConstructor<any>'.
  Property 'displayName' does not exist on type '(props: any) =>
    ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null'.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```js
function getComponentDisplayName(element: React.ReactElement<any>) {
  const node = element as React.ReactElement<React.ComponentType<any>>;
  const type = (node as unknown as React.ReactElement<React.FunctionComponent>)
    .type;
  const displayName =
    typeof type === 'function'
      ? (type as React.FunctionComponent).displayName ||
        (type as React.FunctionComponent).name ||
        'Unknown'
      : type;
  return displayName;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think I solved it:

```
export function extractType(node: unknownElement): Function | string {
  return ((node as unknown) as React.ReactElement).type;
}
export function extractDisplayName(type: React.FunctionComponent): string {
  return type.displayName || type.name || "Unknown";
}
```

Then call it:

```
const type = extractType(node);
if (typeof type === "function") {
  const displayName = extractDisplayName((type as unknown) as React.FunctionComponent);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Try using `Component.type.name` instead of `Component.type.displayName`